# spider my website for a line of code

Tags: web-crawlers

I want to find out which pages on my website (I use blogger) have a specific line of code.
For example, I want to know which pages contain the code:

> "div class='sss'"

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Look at the source and search for it?

Comment: @Rob If it's hosted on blogger they don't have access to the source code for the site.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Hit ctl-u in any browser. Bam. Instant access.

Comment: @Rob - They'd have to do that for each page. I would imagine, since OP is asking here, that makes a page-by-page search a non-trivial matter.

Answer (score 2):

First, list out the URLs to search in a text file. Use a utility like `wget` or `aria` to download the source codes to your local machine. Both these utilities have options to specify a list of URLs to download via text file as input. For example, `wget` uses `--input-file=file` option. Once downloaded to a folder on the local machine, you should be able to use a utility like `grep` to scan for the specified string within files. Or you may use any software or in-build search in your operating system (depending on availability) to search within files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any search engine that would index your website's code.

However, all is not necessarily lost.

You could use a site-ripper to download the whole website to your computer, then use a tool capable of searching through text files for instances of a string you specify (free examples of both can be found online for your preferred OS). This would then highlight every example of `div class='sss'` and the files it is found in can then be directly related to the pages of your site.

I accept that this is fairly long-winded and, since I can only assume it's because you want to make a change to all such instances in your site, laborious to use. But I can't, off the top of my head, think of better way to do it.